# How can I apply Exclusive-OR (XOR) operator to multiple predicates?

Tags: c, operators

I want to know is there a way to apply Exclusive-OR (for two operands it is called XOR) operator to multiple predicates?

For example suppose that `p`, `q` and `r` are three predicates (in other words Boolean variables). I want to write an `if` condition like this:

```
if ((p || q || r) && !(p && q && r))
```

i.e. I want the condition be true if at least one of them is true but not all of them.

Apparently `if (p ^ q ^ r)` will not work (consider the case `p=true`, `q=true` and `r=false`)

Thank you.

---

I got a good answer for **c** language but it is interesting for me to know is there a solution in **c#**?

Comment: Please create a different question for C#, it will be better for you and for people trying to answer your second question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
if ((!!p + !!q + !!r) % 3)
```

But that's probably too clever for its own good.

*Edit:*

```
if (((p ? 1 : 0) + (q ? 1 : 0) + (r ? 1 : 0)) % 3 != 0)  // C#-compatible version
```

Comment: Very clever, but possibly more expensive instruction-wise. Pure logical operators are faster IMO. But here's my also "slow" solution: if ((p?1:0) + (q?1:0) + (r?1:0) == 1)

Comment: That doesn't work. Quoting from the question: *(consider the case p=true, q=true and r=false)*

Comment: Ok, int total = (p?1:0) + (q?1:0) + (r?1:0); if (total > 0 && total < 3) :)

Comment: The question says they are Boolean variables, so why double-not them?

Comment: Because C has no type called `Boolean`, so they could be anything.

Comment: Thanks. That was a clever answer. What if I had this problem in c#?

Comment: Bardia: C# equivalent would be to cast boolean to int (0/1 more precisely) one way or another. And also result should be compared == to 1.

Comment: @SmartK8 yes in the low level they will convert to `int` but when you are coding in c# if you type `if(true == 1)` you will get this error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

Comment: I mean `bool` and `int` are two different types in high level c#.

Comment: Sure, but (((int)p + (int)q + (int)r) % 3) is int, when compared to == 1, it is int to int (Int32).

Comment: It is not acceptable in c#: Cannot convert type 'bool' to 'int'

Comment: Oh, I didn't meant it literally as code (more like meta-code). My bad. I meant cast boolean to int (0/1 more precisely) one way or another. As melpomene said p?1:0 for example. Or slower, but more readable Convert.ToInt32(p)

Comment: @melpomene If you mean `(p ? true : false)` the answer is still `bool` not `int`. Unless we write a `bool` to `int` type casting function.

Comment: ... no, I meant what I said.

Comment: Bardia: No, melpomene is right. (p?1:0) => int, you said (p?true:false) => boolean. Why? Nobody knows. But (p?1:0) is faster equivalent to Convert.ToInt32(p).

Comment: @melpomene Oh oh yes you are right. I misunderstood you. Yes that will work.

Comment: I'm C# programmer for many years, believe me (or try for yourself): if ((((p?1:0) + (q?1:0) + (r?1:0)) % 3) == 1) will work.

Comment: @SmartK8 You are right I accepted it in my prior comment. I misunderstood. I am thinking to the on the comparison of speed of two methods that you mentioned in your previous comment.

Comment: :) p?1:0 is basically syntax sugar for if (p) return 1; else return 0; Convert.ToInt32() is again (decompiled) p?1:0 + 1 method call. So I would say that pure p?1:0 is slightly faster, but on the other hand readability increases with Convert.ToInt32().

Answer (score 2):

What you want is actually not XOR applied to three or more arguments, so the question from title is misleading. XOR's generalization is basically checking if number of true values is odd, which is what `(p ^ q ^ r)` expression calculates.

C does not have any operator that would check your condition (“at least one of them is true but not all of them”), so your notation of:

```
((p || q || r) && !(p && q && r))
```

seems the most idiomatic in C.

Comment: Yes you are right. I found out my mistakes after posting this question. It is not generalized version of exclusive-OR. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: When compiled, the operator-only version will be faster. There are plenty of boolean optimizations along the way. So rest assured this is OK. If you are seeking syntax sugar. Use function: IsAtLeastOneButNotAll* (* label is subject to change)